# Allowing owner (A) to sign exclusively with owner (C) or (D) but forbidding him to sign with owner (B)

Tags: gnosis-safe

Is it possible to have a 4 owners contract where 2 owners are needed to sign, and where owner of the same "group" wallets A/B and wallets C/D **can't** sign together?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could use multiple nested safes to do so: you could have a main Safe  with 2 owners and threshold 2, each of these being a Safe: Safe Group A and Safe Group B. Each of the Group Safes has threshold 1. This way you need 2 signers overall, and at least one from each group.

Did that answer your question?

Best,
Louis